# Excel-VBA; Copy data from excel and paste it in to a word template at different places

Tags: excel, vba

I have some data in an Excel Sheet which have been pull from the master data in another sheet by the VBA. The data is showing in excel sheet in column A & B.

And I have an MS-Word template as detail below:

“ An estimate amounting to Rs. [B1] based on approved rates for the above [B2] was sanctioned by the competent authority. Against this estimate tenders amounting to Rs. [B3] were invited vide Tender No. [B4] Dated [B5] which has opened on [B7] 
This estimate for Rs. [B1] has been approved on [b5] ”

I want to create a macro in the Excel by which the value of different cells of column ‘B’ be paste in template in place of respective [ ] to create a new word doc.

Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your data is in cells B1 to B7 of "Sheet1", then the following code will paste the required text into the document "C:\TestFolder\Test.docx". You can obviously edit the filenames and pathnames to suit.

```
Sub PasteStuffIntoWord()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim TextToPaste As String
Dim objWord As Object
Dim objSelection As Object

Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")
With ws
    TextToPaste = "An estimate amounting to Rs. " & .Range("B1").Value & _
    " based on approved rates for the above " & .Range("B2").Value & _
    " was sanctioned by the competent authority. Against this estimate tenders amounting to Rs. " _
    & .Range("B3").Value & " were invited vide Tender No. " & .Range("B4").Value & " Dated " _
    & .Range("B5").Value & " which has opened on " & .Range("B7").Value & " This estimate for Rs. " _
    & .Range("B1").Value & " has been approved on " & .Range("B5").Value
End With

    Set objWord = CreateObject("word.Application")
    objWord.documents.Open "C:\TestFolder\Test.docx"
    objWord.Visible = True
    Set objSelection = objWord.Selection
    objSelection.TypeText TextToPaste

End Sub
```