# Insert graphs from Excel to Word

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

Hi this is a follow up question from my previous question: [Insert text to Word from Excel looping through drop down list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68101610/insert-text-to-word-from-excel-looping-through-drop-down-list/)

In addition to inserting text, I need to insert graphs for every region and copy the graph under each text. The graphs changes with the data for every region and is located next to the data table.

So the result has to look like this:

Text 1

Graph 1

Text 2

Graph 2 etc.

The code that inserts text (see from the previous question):

```
Sub Export()
Dim reg As Variant, col As String, txt As String

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet 1")
    For Each reg In Array("Region1", "Region2", "Region3")
        .Range("B3") = reg
        .Calculate
        
        col = IIf(.Range("D2").Value = 14, "C", "D")    'select column due to D2 value
        
        ' collect all texts in txt
        txt = txt & vbTab & "For " & reg & ", on June, 21 the estimate was " & _
        .Range(col & "6").Text & " and the volume was " & .Range(col & "7").Text & _
        " and the variance was  " & .Range(col & "8").Text & vbLf
    Next
End With

With CreateObject("Word.Application").Documents.Add
    .Range.Text = txt    ' output all text to the document
    .SaveAs "C:\temp\AllTheText.docx"  ' your path and name
    .Parent.Quit    'quit Word
End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry this isn't a bonafide answer, I don't have the reputation to ask a follow up question...

Have you considered copying the chart from Excel into Word, then issuing a Refresh command on the chart in Word once data is updated in Excel? You could then create a "AlltheTextTemplate" Word file with the charts preset. You'd then just create a copy of the template when creating a new report, fill it in with the data, and create a small bit of code to refresh the chart object.

Here's a few lines you could add:

```
Set wordapp = CreateObject("Word.Application")

' Path listed here assumes the template is stored in the same DIR as the workbook
Set objDoc = wordapp.documents.Open(Application.ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Template.docx") 

wordapp.Visible = True 'Remove if you don't need to see it

With ObjDoc
    .Range.Text = txt    ' output all text to the document
    .InlineShapes(1).LinkFormat.Update 'update the shape ID as needed
    .InlineShapes(1).LinkFormat.BreakLink 'If you want to break the data link
    .SaveAs "C:\temp\AllTheText.docx"  ' your path and name
    .Parent.Quit    'quit Word
End With
```